# How to detect whether notification id exists or not?

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, intentservice

Is it possible to detect if a notification attached with a unique id exists in the notifications bar?

```
mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

For example, I created the notification with id **100**. Next time when I create a notification with **that id** again, I don't want it updated. I used `setOnlyAlertOnce(true)`, the sound is gone but it still updates that notification and moves it to the top.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from API Level 23 (Android M) you can get a list of active notifications and find a notification with a given id.

```
StatusBarNotification[] notifications = 
    mNotificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
for (StatusBarNotification notification : notifications) {
  if (notification.getId() == 100) {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

On earlier versions you need to persist information about notifications you created and handle notification deletion by setting `deleteIntent` when creating a notification.

Comment: Yes, that would work but i cannot change to API Level 23. Can i ask you one more question? How can i use `HttpURLConnection` in a class that extended from `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: You should create another question for this problem. But the short answer is to start a service.

Answer (score 0):

```
private lateinit var manager2: NotificationManager
manager2 = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

val notificationDownload: Array<StatusBarNotification> = manager2.activeNotifications
if (notificationDownload.isNotEmpty()) {
    for (notification in notificationDownload) {
     if (notification.id == 11223344) { // id notif on showing
       // Write your condition if id is equal same as notification id on show status bar
     } else {
       // Write your condition if id not equal as notif status bar.
     }
   }
} else { // Your condition if empty notif in status bar }
```